# How can I give a text input a default value in Elixir/Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this field

```
  <%= number_input f, :duration_minutes %>
```

and I would like to give it a default of 60. How can I do that?

The obvious guess of

```
  <%= number_input f, :duration_minutes, default: 60 %>
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update based on the comment from Allen:

```
  schema "events" do
    field :duration_minutes, :integer, default: 60
  end
```

Here is my previous answer that isn't as robust according to him:

```
  <%= number_input f, :duration_minutes, value: 60 %>
```

Comment: BTW, this won't work well if it's changed from the default value in the changeset on an error. In that case, it's better to set the default in the schema.